# Can't import an Android project that was cloned from GIT into an eclipse workspace

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I want to be able to clone a project into my workspace, and than import it into Eclipse.
When I choose "Import"->"Import existing Android code into workspace", I get:

> Invalid project description. [ProjectName] overlaps the location of another project: [ProjectName]

When I choose "Import"->"Existing projects into workspace" I get nothing to import (because I keep only the "res" folder, "src" folder and AndroidManifest.xml files in the git repo.

Any solution that involves copying the repo outside the workspace and importing it will not work since I want it to be cloned into my workspace.

How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you do not have a directory named [ProjectName] in your workspace. If so delete it. After several tries I would not be surprised that the assistant created it and therefore is not letting you import it because it thinks it exists.

Then, git clone the project outside of your workspace.

Finally, go to new->Android project from existing source, select the cloned directory and make sure you tick the box : **Copy the files into workspace**

That should work.

**UPDATE AFTER COMMENT :**

Ok, I didn't understand the part about the direct to workspace import.

I just tried and had no problem :

1. clone the github project inside the workspace
2. In Eclipse : Right click in the Package Explorer
3. Click "Import...",
4. Under the directory Android choose : "Existing Android code into workspace"
5. Browse to your project directory
6. Make sure **not to tick** the "Copy projects into workspace"
7. Click finish

Comment: That will work, but I wanted to avoid that complication and immediately clone into the workspace. I guess that since it copies all of the git files as well its ok, but isn't there a way to avoid this?

Comment: That is exactly what I do when I receive the error I posted in my questions :/